# How to select all rows where date column are like a '2015-01-21'?

Tags: mysql, date

Im' trying to select all the rows with a concrete user and also on a specific date. My query always return "0", and this is no possible.

The column called "date-column" have a DATE format.

```
$my_date = '2015-01-21';

$q_search = $mysqli->query("SELECT *
                   FROM table_name
                   WHERE userID = ".$_SESSION['memberID']." AND
                        date_column = ".$my_date."");

echo 'number of results: '.$q_search->num_rows.';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to include single quote  in your WHERE clause. e.g `WHERE userID = ' ".$_SESSION['memberID']." ' AND date_column = ' ".$my_date." '`

Comment: What is the type of `date_column`?  If it includes a time portion then it will be very unlikely date+time to match a date-only constant.   That would only happen for records with a time of midnight.

Comment: Are you only looking for the count?  If so, it would be more efficient to do a `SELECT count(*)` and then fetch the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ' in you date, like this

```
$q_search = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userID = ".$_SESSION['memberID']." AND date_column = '" . $my_date . "'");
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Your answer is correct and now is working. My (stupid) mistake!

Comment: @didaquis its normal.

Answer (score 2):

Insert query should be like this

```
   $sql=" SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[memberID]' AND date_column = '$my_date'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the parameters:

```
$q_search = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userID = '".$_SESSION['memberID']."' AND date_column = '".$my_date."';");
```

I suggest you to sanitize the parameters with the function *mysql_real_escape_string* before concatenating them in the query, like that:

```
$q_search = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userID = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['memberID'])."' AND date_column = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($my_date)."';");
```

Comment: OP uses MySQLi and yet you're inserting mysql_* commands. Also if he uses already MySQLi, you could also suggest using Prepared Statements instead of escaping.

Comment: assuming you meant `mysqli_real_escape_string`